# excel Copy shapes from one worksheet to another

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

I am trying to use a macro to copy all the shapes (images) from a worksheet to another. I used the record macro to do it, but it always gives an aleatory name to the shape making it impossible to reproduce it when we don't know the name of shapes.

Comment: show your code and your actual issue

Comment: It may also help to read through [how to avoid `.Select`/`.Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will copy all the shapes from `Sheet1` to `Sheet2`:

```
Sub CopyShape()
    Dim s As Shape
    For Each s In Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes
        s.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Paste
    Next s
End Sub
```

Once the copy is complete, you can position them as you like or rename them as you like.
*(An alternative is just to make a copy of the entire worksheet.)*

**EDIT#1:**

This code will also automatically assign Names and positions to the copied Shapes:

```
Sub CopyShape()
    Dim shp1 As Shape, nombre As String
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Dim shp2 As Shape

    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

    For Each shp1 In s1.Shapes
            nombre = shp1.Name
            shp1.Copy
            s2.Paste
            Set shp2 = s2.Shapes(s2.Shapes.Count)
            shp2.Name = nombre
            shp2.Top = shp1.Top
            shp2.Left = shp1.Left
    Next shp1
End Sub
```

Be careful to avoid name conflicts if you perform re-copies.

Comment: the copy / paste works fine thank you a lot. But this answer puts the shapes in the left corner and what I was looking for for to put them in the same position they had in the source worksheet

Comment: @HugoSilva  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Set shp2 = s2.Shapes(s2.Shapes.Count) returns me error (object required)

Comment: @HugoSilva  I can't reproduce the error you are seeing.

Comment: @HugoSilva  Try starting with no shapes on `Sheet2`

Comment: sheet 2 is a blank sheet. still not working.... there is not a workaround?

Comment: @HugoSilva are you using `Sheet2` or `Sheet 2`?

Comment: neither :) I am using sheets with given names. I managed to resove the issue according to the info on this link https://excelribbon.tips.net/T011333_Copying_Pictures_with_a_Macro.html. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I've added the means to place the Shape in the target Sheet at about the same location. Below is how I use it.

```
    Private Sub CopyShape(ByVal shp_source As Shape, _
                          ByVal wsh_target As Worksheet, _
                          ByRef shp_target As Shape)
    ' -------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Copies the Shape (shp_source) to Worksheet (wsh_target) and returns
    ' the target Shape (shp_target). Places the  Shape on the target
    ' sheet at the same cell (row/column) as the source Shape.
    ' -------------------------------------------------------------------
        Dim rng As Range

        Set rng = wsh_target.Cells(shp_source.TopLeftCell.Row, shp_source.TopLeftCell.Column)
        shp_source.Copy
        wsh_target.Paste rng
        Set shp_target = wsh_target.Shapes(wsh_target.Shapes.Count)
        With shp_target
           .Name = shp_source.Name
           .Top = shp_source.Top
           .Left = shp_source.Left
        End With

    End Sub
```