# VBA Excel - copy object to last active sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an object located on a different sheet, which I would like to copy to the last active sheet. Unfortunately, the code I have throws an error:

**Object doesn't support this property or method**

```
Sub AddCabinet()
Dim MooSheet, CurrentSheet As Worksheet
Set CurrentSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set MooSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cab Templates")

MooSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("VHPOPA")).Select
Selection.Copy
CurrentSheet.Range("A1").Paste
End Sub
```

How can I copy an object to my previous current sheet? I have a few sheets with the same buttons.

Comment: A range has no `Paste`-method, you need to use `CurrentSheet.Paste`. Shape will be placed into the current active cell.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48950861/7599798

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy Shapes

- Can you even get rid of `Select` and `Activate` when copying multiple shapes? I couldn't.
- My idea was to copy the shape(s) and restore the worksheets initial selections.
- The array is useful to copy multiple shapes. Note that if you don't explicitly use the array function as the parameter for the [`Shape.Range property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shapes.range), you need to evaluate the array by putting it into parentheses, if its variable is declared as a variant without parentheses i.e.:

  ```
  Dim shpArr() As Variant... sws.Shapes.Range(shpArr).Select
  ' or:
  Dim shpArr As Variant  ... sws.Shapes.Range((shpArr)).Select
  ```

**The Flow**

- Exit if the workbook containing this code (`ThisWorkbook`) is not the active workbook (`ActiveWorkbook`). Exit if the active sheet (`ActiveSheet`) is not a worksheet. Reference the active sheet i.e. the destination worksheet.
- Reference the source worksheet. Exit if it's the destination worksheet.
- Reference the destination **Selection** to restore after the job is done. Reference the destination cell. **Activate** it, if it's not active.
- **Select** the source worksheet. Reference its **Selection** to restore it after the job is done. **Select** all shapes whose names are in the array and copy them using **Selection**.
- **Activate** the destination worksheet and paste. Restore its initial selection using **Select**.
- **Select** the source workbook to restore its initial selection using **Select**.
- **Select** the destination worksheet.

```vb
Sub AddCabinet()
            
    ' Define constants.
    Const sName As String = "Cab Templates"
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "A1"
    Dim shpArr() As Variant: shpArr = Array("VHPOPA")
    'Dim shpArr() As Variant: shpArr = Array("Oval 1", "Oval 2")
            
    ' Reference ThisWorkbook's active sheet, the destination worksheet ('dws').
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    If Not wb Is ActiveWorkbook Then Exit Sub ' another workbook is active
    If Not TypeOf ActiveSheet Is Worksheet Then Exit Sub ' not a worksheet
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.ActiveSheet ' or 'ActiveSheet'
    
    ' Reference the source worksheet ('sws')
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    If sws Is dws Then Exit Sub ' source and destination are the same
    
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Reference the destination cell ('dCell') and activate if not active.
    Dim dSel As Object: Set dSel = Selection ' store
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dws.Range(dFirstCellAddress)
    If Not dCell Is ActiveCell Then dCell.Activate ' ensure it's active
    
    ' Copy.
    sws.Select
    Dim sSel As Object: Set sSel = Selection ' store
    sws.Shapes.Range(shpArr).Select
    Selection.Copy
    
    ' Paste.
    With dws
        .Activate
        .Paste
    End With
    If Not dSel Is Nothing Then dSel.Select ' restore
    
    sws.Select
    If Not sSel Is Nothing Then sSel.Select ' restore
    
    dws.Select

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

`.paste` is a `worksheet` method, not a `range` method, that is where the error is coming from.

We can remove all the `Select`s to make this a bit cleaner.

```
    Dim MooSheet As Worksheet, CurrentSheet As Worksheet
    Set CurrentSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set MooSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cab Templates")
    MooSheet.Shapes("VHPOPA").Copy
    CurrentSheet.Paste
```

Comment: Yes but how about if I want to paste the object at the current range?

Comment: `CurrentSheet.Paste Selection`

Answer (score 1):

Before copying the object need to be there in that sheet, solve the problem...
try this...

```
Sub AddCabinet()
Dim MooSheet, CurrentSheet As Worksheet
Set CurrentSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set MooSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cab Templates")

MooSheet.Select
MooSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("VHPOPA")).Select
Selection.Copy

CurrentSheet.Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Hope it Helps...